# Forking Git repo after making changes

Tags: git

I made changes to the Laravel Homestead repo and just decided I'd actually like to fork them. Can I do a Git fork on my local changes? Or do I need to fork the original and then just manually copy over my changes?

Comment: Where exactly did you make these changes? In a local git clone of the repo?

In git, a clone *is* a fork. (Though the term fork might mean something different if you're talking about GitHub.)

Comment: All I did was clone the Homestead repo onto my computer, made changes and then realized I want to commit them to my own repo so I can pull them if I switch computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just copied the project instead of cloning it,  you can use

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

to configure the repository you want to fork.

Then update your local references from the remote with `git fetch`.

If you committed changes to your local repository and the remote has new changes you'll have to merge your changes or use [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Your `.git/config` file should now contain:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = <url>
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: -1 There is no need to do anything of that for fork. Once you've cloned a repository, you already forked it.

Comment: True, I just had the impression he might not have cloned it.  Are you grilling me on the definition of "fork"?

Comment: I cloned it from the original. I now have a local copy. I want to commit and push my changes to my own separate repo for use elsewhere.

Comment: Use the same command as in this answer, just replace `origin` with another name: `git remote add myrepo <url>`.  You will be able to push to it with `git push myrepo master`.